# How to get count of 'li' elements list with selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium

I have this html. I am trying to count total number of li elements inside the ul element. Even though there are 20 li elements but DOM shows less than 20.

```
 <ul class="a-pagination">
    <li class="a-disabled">←<span class="a-letter-space"></span><span class="a-letter-space"></span>Previous</li>
        <li class="a-selected"><a href="ff" aria-current="page">1</a></li>
        <li class="a-normal"><a href="www">2</a></li>
        <li class="a-normal"><a href="ddddddddddd">3</a></li>
        <li class="a-disabled" aria-disabled="true">...</li>
        <li class="a-disabled" aria-disabled="true">20</li>
        <li class="a-last"><a href="/">Next<span class="a-letter-space"></span><span class="a-letter-space"></span>→</a></li>
    
    </ul>
```

Selenium should count the li elements inside the ul class because there are other li elements outside the ul class.

I have this:

```
          List<WebElement> list1 = driver.findElements("not sure what will go here");
          System.out.println("\nsize" + list1.size() );
```

What should be the locator to find the total li elements under the ul class? It should return the value of 20.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this css selector :

```
ul.a-pagination li
```

like this :

```
List<WebElement> list1 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.a-pagination li"));
```

and print like the way you are printing.

Comment: I tried with your code. It returns a value of 7. As you can see DOM also shows 7 li elements so it returns 7 but there are 20 li elements which can be found only by clicking the Next button 20 times.

Comment: Can you share the page url ?

Comment: Sorry! I cant due to security.